# How to create a 'fog of war' bitmap overlay in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, overlay, transparent, fog

I have a simple 2D game with a handful of characters which move around the screen. I'd like to create a fog of war, whereby only the background around each character is visible.

Hopefully that's clear (not too foggy?!?!). My thoughts were to create a black bitmap, then draw a 'transparent' disk centered on each of the characters. Then I can draw the background, draw the characters and finally draw this overlay bitmap over the top.

Just not sure how to draw the 'transparent' disks on to the black bitmap.

Any ideas, or alternative designs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Canvas.drawCircle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) with a [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object whose [alpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAlpha%28int%29) is set to 0. Alternatively you could create a transparent circle with a Bitmap and draw it just like another bitmap.  The Bitmap based circle would be more advantageous if you wanted strong control with a fade to black.

1. Create a bitmap to hold the black overlay
2. Fill bitmap with black
3. Paint a transparent circle over it of where you whant to punch holes
4. Paint the overlay over your game canvas
5. Repeat.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get the detail. In your first suggestion, is that creating a second canvas? My canvas contains my background image. I then draw my characters on top of that. I then want to overlay the whole lot with a black bitmap, with the areas around the characters 'punched out'. In your second suggestion, how would I get the transparent circle to reveal the background, not just make a hole in the black?

Comment: Cheers, but I'm still not sure what settings I need in my paint to draw the transparent circle. I just have a new Paint and setAlpha to 0, but that just draws a transparent circle, leaving what's below as black.

Comment: Try `Paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`.

Comment: Cheers! That's working now. I've had a bit of trouble with this, but it's working now. Thanks for your help. I had to set a PorterDuff mode (whatever that is!) too

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since the fog-of-war needs to be persistent, I've had to go for an opaque tiled solution, rather than a straight bitmap, as the bitmap was too large and took too long to load/save between activations.